# Return url query string with map()

Tags: jquery

I want this script to return me an url query string depending on what is checked on a list-item element.

```
function makeQuery(){
    var catRes = $('.options input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(", ");
    $('.catQuery').val(catRes);
}

$('.options input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    makeQuery();
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" class="catQuery" value="< map() result here >"/>
<ul class="options">
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="url1"/>Item 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="url2"/>Item 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="url3"/>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I know that the result I get is now url1,url2,url3 but I would like that it create a string equivalent to this

> ?url1=1&url2=1...

Depending on which input is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function makeQuery() {
    var catRes = $('.options input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val() + "=1";
    }).get().join("&");
    $('.catQuery').val(catRes);
}

$('.options input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    makeQuery();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejVEg/1/)

Comment: I knew it was that simple hehe. Thanks